# CSS Align image in the center error

Tags: css

I have a < div > called container which wrap an image and another small < d i v >.
The problem is , I'm trying to align the image in the  center of the container.
If it's a big image . It will fit in the middle but if it's an small image , it will lean to the left side . How can I make the image position in the middle? without using margin . Because if I use margin , the small image will be in the center but the big image will lean to the right side.

My CSS

```
 .container{background-color: #ED8713; 
 height: 300px; 
 width: 300px;
 margin: 60px;}

 .box6{background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 270px;height:80px;
 margin: 5px;}
 img {margin: 10px;}
```

My HTML

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="float.css">



<div class="container"><img src="s.jpg"/>
                    <div class="box6"></div>

</div>

<div class="container"><img src="q.jpg"/>
                    <div class="box6"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your CSS this way:

```
img {margin: 10px auto; display: block;}
```

Comment: Okay that one is perfect only for firefox . How we also make for internet explorer?

Comment: IE works too... I checked in IE 8, IE 9, FF and Chrome... Hey did you give a `<!DOCTYPE>`?

Comment: o.0 Are you sure man . I'm tapping on my refresh page at IE 9 5 times

Comment: nah  , it just stay the same . but firefox google chrome . it all works expect IE

Comment: Oi You are right . I got to put this <!DOCTYPE html>
thank man

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapper div for your image and set the css for the wrapper div to;

```
#wrapper {text-align: center;}
```

This will set all elements in the wrapper to the center of the container as the wrapper div will be 100% width of the parent div as it is a block element.

Full example

```
#wrapper {text-align: center;}

<div id="container">
    <div id="wrapper"><img /></div>
    <div id="small"><p>Some text</p></div>
</div>
```

Or you could possibly use margin auto to automatically set the margin widths to be equal on the `img`;

```
image {margin: 0 auto;}
```

But you said you didn't want to use margin, the choice is yours!

Good luck

Comment: img {text-align: center;}  is this what u mean?

Comment: Try the first example in my answer, it will work on all browsers

Answer (score 1):

Try this .  [W3C](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html)

http://jsfiddle.net/QsN6q/

```
img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto }
```

Comment: It work perfectly but the issue is , it doesn't work in IE? how can we make it work?

Comment: Which version of IE. This is W3C Standard of centering image.

Comment: I see it fine in IE 9. Are u in Quirks mode?

Comment: i think so . I found the solution . I had to put this <!DOCTYPE html>